# Multiple where inside a where statement

Tags: laravel

I would like to generate a query in Laravel that gives the following results:

From the results obtained from

```
$results = DB::table('records')->where('email', '!=', 'test@gmail.com')->get();
```

Do multiple where statements like this:

```
->where('id', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%')
->orWhere('email', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%')
->orWhere('recordType', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%')
->orWhere('uploadDate', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%')
->orWhere('uploadTime', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%')
->get();
```

How should I phrase the statement in controller to produce the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`where()` closure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#parameter-grouping) to group parameters:

```
$results = DB::table('records')->where('email', '!=', 'test@gmail.com')
    ->where(function($q) use($request) {
        $q->where('id', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
          ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
          ->orWhere('recordType', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
          ->orWhere('uploadDate', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
          ->orWhere('uploadTime', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%');
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: sorry, the comment was added before you added the group params. it worked like a charm :D