# Convert SQL to Eloquent Query Builder : Laravel5.5

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

How can I convert this SQL to Laravel5.5 Eloquent format

`select * from 'arm_articles' where ('article_tag' like '%standard%' or 'article_topic' like '%standard%' or 'article_details' like '%standard%' or 'article_type' like '%standard%') and ( ('id' between 287 and 296) and 'article_active' = 1) order by 'id' desc`

**Please observer the braces in the SQL**

This is the one i wrote that returns a different sql when i tested the output using **->toSql**

`$post=  PostModel::where('article_tag','like','%'.$contributor_id.'%')->orWhere('article_topic','like','%'.$contributor_id.'%')->orWhere('article_details','like','%'.$contributor_id.'%')->orWhere('article_type','like','%'.$contributor_id.'%')->whereBetween('id', [$end, $start-1])->where('article_active',1)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(10)->get();`

Find the SQL output from the query above

`select * from 'arm_articles' where 'article_tag' like ? or 'article_topic' like ? or 'article_details' like ? or 'article_type' like ? and 'id' between ? and ? and 'article_active' = ? order by 'id' desc limit 10`

This output looks like the needed SQL, but the different is the braces on the SQL. so one coin the Eloquent Query Builder to come out with the braces on the query  ?

Comment: Use [parameter grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#parameter-grouping)

Comment: You can also use this online tool in oder to convert your raw SQL into Laravel Builder: http://www.midnightcowboycoder.com/

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`where()` closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48429630/1227923) for [parameter grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#parameter-grouping):

```
PostModel::where(function($q) use($contributor_id) {
        $q->where('article_tag', 'like', '%' . $contributor_id . '%')
          ->orWhere('article_topic', 'like', '%' . $contributor_id . '%')
          ->orWhere('article_details', 'like', '%' . $contributor_id . '%')
          ->orWhere('article_type', 'like', '%' . $contributor_id . '%');
    })
    ->whereBetween('id', [$end, $start - 1])
    ->where('article_active', 1)
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48975428/passport-laravel-rest-api-auth-with-normal-design/48980081?noredirect=1#comment84984839_48980081
can you see my ques.?

Answer (score 3):

Try with this

```
$post = PostModel::where(function ($query) use ($contributor_id) {              
          $query->orWhere('article_topic','like','%'.$contributor_id.'%')
          ->orWhere('article_details','like','%'.$contributor_id.'%')
          ->orWhere('article_type','like','%'.$contributor_id.'%')
          ->orwhere('article_tag','like','%'.$contributor_id.'%');
        })->whereBetween('id', [$end, $start-1])
        ->where('article_active',1)
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->take(10)
        ->get();
```

Alexey Mezenin did it before me.